# how to print a list<class*> ls?

Tags: c++

What am I doing wrong at the last two lines in my code below? I receive an error:

> request for member `‘name’` in `‘t.std::_List_iterator<_Tp>::operator* [with _Tp = a*]()’`, which is of non-class type `‘a*’`

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "/home/developer/Desktop/MsgSphSDK1/test1_sdk/libsdk_MS.hpp"
#include <list>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class a
{
public:
    string name;
    int age;
};

int main()
{
    a* l = new a();
    l->name = "me";
    l->age = 1;

    list<a*> ls;
    list<a*>::iterator t;

    for (t = ls.begin(); t != ls.end(); ++t) 
        cout << (*t).name << endl;
}
```

Comment: why `main()` is not returning something?

Comment: @Donotalo: Because it doesn't need to.

Comment: @Xeo: Yes, it does. But you don't have to tell it to. :)

Comment: Why are you using dynamic allocation here? What's wrong with a `std::list<a>`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should write

```
cout<<(*t)->name<<endl
```

`t` is an iterator, `(*t)` gives you `a*` (the pointer to the object of class `a`). So to get access to the member of the object you should use `->`, not `.`.